# Can't correctly get content from a file

Tags: c++

```
struct data
{
 int record;
 string fName;
 string lName;
 string phoneNum;
};

string line, lastname, firstname, phone;

vector<data> readContent()
{
 inFile.open("data.txt");
 vector<data> myData;
 char recordstring[4];
 data datas;

 inFile.clear();
 while(inFile >> recordstring)
 {  
    int records;
    records = atoi(recordstring);
    datas.record  = records;
    getline(inFile, firstname, ' ');
    datas.fName = firstname;
    getline(inFile, lastname, ' ');
    datas.lName = lastname;
    getline(inFile, phone, '\n');
    datas.phoneNum = phone;
    myData.push_back(datas);
 }
 inFile.close();
 return myData;
}
```

This is the input file (data.txt):

> 1000 q q 1
>   1001 w w 2
>   1002 e e 3
>   1003 r r 4
>   1004 t t 5

This is what the debugger shows for the first line in the file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjhCc.png

Can anyone see what is wrong with it?
It should be 1000 being the record, q for fname, q for lname and 1 for phonenum (for the first line).  All I am doing is storing each line in an struct instance (data) and then store that into a vector to be used later.

Comment: BTW: You're overflowing recordstring as `basic_istream::operator>>` stores a terminating nul-character, see §27.7.2.2.3[istream::extractors] in the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read from a file word by word, then stay with `>>`. If you want to read it line by line then use `std::getline`, but don't mix these two in this manner.

Also note that you have:

1. declared `char recordstring[4]`
2. tried to initialize it using `std::cin >> recordstring`
3. tried to convert it to `int` using `atoi`

...while simple `>>` used to fill a variable of type `int` would do. Note that the size of `recordstring` is 4, which is big enough to hold 3 characters + null-terminating `'\0'`

Actually the whole reading could be simple as:

```
vector<data> myData;

data d;
while(inFile >> d.record >> d.fName >> d.lName >> d.phoneNum) {  
    myData.push_back(d);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`inFile >> recordstring` does not consume the trailing whitespace, so the first getline() call returns an empty string because the first character it consumes is the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

If the file format is fixed as shown, simply do following :-

```
while(inFile >> datas.record >> datas.fName >> datas.lName >> datas.phoneNum)
   myData.push_back(datas);
```

Your logic seems to skip white space for `recordstring`

Comment: There's no reason to use `atoi`: `inFile >> datas.record` will work.

Comment: @user786653 yup, I didn't notice that